# Theoretical result for probability problem to cut rod s.t. it makes triangle doesn't match the actual experiment.

Tags: probability, python

I was solving the following probability problem yesterday:

Given a rod of length L, find the number of ways to cut the rod into thre parts s.t. these parts form a triangle.

Now, it's a standard problem and multiple solutions can be found online. Added a few links in solutions (Feel free to go and explore). Obviously, all of them arrive at the same conclusion that the required probability is 1 / 4 = 0.25.

Then, I decided to conduct an experiment and write a python script to simulate the experiment. I perform the experiment 10^7 times (takes a while to calculate the result) but always comes up with ~0.19 no matter what I choose number of experiments and length of rod to be.

I would like to find out why theoretical and practical result doesn't match?

Here is my python script:

```
import numpy as np

def rod_cut(L):
    x = np.random.uniform(0, L)
    y = np.random.uniform(0, L - x)
    z = L - (x + y)
    return (x, y, z)


def is_triangle(datapoint):
    a, b, c = datapoint
    return a + b >= c and \
           b + c >= a and \
           a + c >= b

def perform_experiment():
    N = 10000000
    L = 1.0
    datapoints = [rod_cut(L) for _ in range(N)]
    successes = sum([is_triangle(datapoint) for datapoint in datapoints])
    print("Probability of cutting rod s.t it makes a triangle = ", successes / N)

perform_experiment()
```

*Note: I tried making a frequency distribution graph of the random numbers that `numpy` generates and it comes out to be uniform. So I trust that `numpy.random.uniform` is generating a uniform distribution of random numbers as expected.*

*Solution based on algebraic inequalities:*
1. (From quora) [https://www.quora.com/A-rod-is-broken-into-three-parts-what-is-the-probability-that-the-three-parts-can-be-arranged-to-form-a-triangle]

Comment: This looks like a different problem.  Your $y$ is not chosen uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @lulu, the way I cut the rod is this:  
**x** is the length of first cut.  (can be between 0 to L)
**y** is the length of second cut. (can be between 0 to L - x because x is already taken from the rod)  
**z** is rest of the rod (which is L - (x + y))

I think it covers all the possible cases.

Comment: Ok, but then you require that the second cut be to the right of $x$.  The original problem has $x,y$ both uniform on $[0,1]$.  If instead of "first"  you require $x$ to be the left most cut, then $x$ is no longer uniform.  (knowing that $x$ is leftmost is evidence for the fact that $x$ is small).

Comment: x and y aren't the cut-positions on the rod but the length of the rod because I later use them as length of sides of triangle formed.

Comment: As I say, the length of the left most segment isn't a uniform variable.

Comment: For instance, your $x$ has a $.01$ chance of being $≥.99$ (taking $L=1$), same for $x≤.01$.  But the probability that the (properly constructed "triangle") has a side of length $≥.99$ is $2\times .01^2$.

Comment: [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/polymath/mitprimes2017b/p/expected-extrema) is a link which discusses some standard variants of the stick breaking problem.  Yours is discussed in Problem $3$ and the theoretical answer is shown to be $\ln(2)-\frac 12\approx 0.193147181$ which, of course, is in line with your simulation.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases:-

**Case -I** : you select 2 random points (X,Y) and then break the sticks at these two joints.

Then your r.v's: $X\sim Uni(0,l) \qquad Y\sim Uni(0,l) , \text{ are independent}$

Now you have got 3 pieces, $X,Y,L-(X+Y)$

If you remember there is a basic property of a triangle  **Sum of two sides should be more than the third side.**

SO you need work these 3 subcases :
$$ P(X+Y \ge l-(X+Y));\quad P(X+ l-(X+Y)\ge Y) ;\quad P(l-(X+Y)+Y \ge X)$$

$\Rrightarrow P(X+Y \ge l-(X+Y))=  P(2X+2Y \ge l)=0.5 $

$\Rrightarrow P( P(X+ l-(X+Y)\ge Y))=  P(l\ge 2Y)=\frac{1}{2} $

$\Rrightarrow P( P(Y+ l-(X+Y)\ge X))=  P(l\ge 2X)=\frac{1}{2} $

and similarly i hope that you can do the  rest of the problem.The answer shall be the product of the subcases.

**Case-II**: You select a random point X on the stick and cut out the piece of length X . Then you take another random point Y on the cut out piece of X and break it at that point.

Then your random variables are :$X\sim Uni(0,l) \quad Y|X=x \sim Uni(0,x)$

Then the the length of the pieces you get:$Y,X-Y,L-X$

Work it out in the similar way as mentioned above and you will get the results.

Hope this helps.